# iPhone not connecting to Windows 10 PC

Tags: wireless-networking, router, itunes, iphone

I am trying to sync an iPhone 11 to my Windows 10 PC over WiFi but it will not connect and I am not really sure why.  I can ping the phone from the PC but I cannot ping the PC from the phone.  They are both on the same network.  The network is 2 Asus RT-AX58Us in a mesh setup.  I have tried to sync on both the 5 GHZ and 2.4 GHZ connections.  I have made sure the check box is checked in iTunes as well.  I have turned beamforming off and on to make sure that was not the issue and have made sure isolation is disabled as well.  I can't figure out if it is an issue with the phone or with my router.  My Android pings my PC just fine and will connect to it over WiFi.  Any idea and what else I can be missing?

Thanks.

EDIT: Sorry I forgot to mention.  I am testing this by trying to sync wirelessly with iTunes.  I can plug the phone in, sync, disconnect the phone, but then it won't resync over WiFi.

Comment: Try syncinng your iPhone with iTunes and see if that works. I use iTunes.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that is what I am using to test.